# Access the request headers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers

How can I access the "request" headers not the response in javascript, I've tried XMLHttpRequest but it doesn't seem to have a method to access the request headers.

Comment: The request headers of the current request? of an Ajax request? For what reason?

Comment: If possible the current request if not I'd be fine with something like XMLHttpRequest which uses the same session or something.

Comment: I don't believe thats possible, what values do you want?

Comment: Set-Cookie HTTP header

Comment: `Set-Cookie:` is in the response, not the request.  The request contains a `cookie:` header, you can see the value of this with `document.cookie`

Comment: I want to get them via headers @Alex K.